Typescript "moduleResolution" "node10" vs "node16"
I am writing an app and I am using the package "express-request-id". The types of the package are included in a types.d.ts file but as it seems, when the "moduleResolution" type is "node16" or "nodenext" the types cannot be referenced from the types.d.ts file. However, when updating the "moduleResolution" to "node" or "node10" the types are correctly referenced. Does anyone had a similar problem? Any insights or solutions?
sandbox
